# background of watermark is black on zubrag watermark Script

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

i am applying watermark onto the image using this [code](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/watermark-image.php%E2%80%8E) why the background of the watermark image is black after applying watermark even the watermark is in png format and it is transparent this is the script [zubrag](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/watermark-image.php)

```
  $image_path = $filename;

  // Where to save watermarked image
  $imgdestpath = $destination_folder . basename($filename);

  // Watermark image
  $img = new Zubrag_watermark($image_path);
  $img->ApplyWatermark($watermark_path);
  $img->SaveAsFile($imgdestpath);
  $img->Free();


  function ApplyWatermark($watermark_path) {

    $this->watermark_path = $watermark_path;

    // Determine image size and type
    $size = getimagesize($this->image_path);
    $size_x = $size[0];
    $size_y = $size[1];
    $image_type = $size[2]; // 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG

    // load source image
    $image = $this->ImageCreateFromType($image_type, $this->image_path);

    // Determine watermark size and type
    $wsize = getimagesize($watermark_path);
    $watermark_x = $wsize[0];
    $watermark_y = $wsize[1];
    $watermark_type = $wsize[2]; // 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG

    // load watermark
    $watermark = $this->ImageCreateFromType($watermark_type, $watermark_path);
    // where do we put watermark on the image?
    $dest_x = $size_x - $watermark_x - $this->offset_x;
    $dest_y = $size_y - $watermark_y - $this->offset_y;
    imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_x, $watermark_y, 100);  

    $this->image = &$image;
    $this->watermark = &$watermark;
    $this->image_type = $image_type;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - change

```
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_x, $watermark_y, 100);
```

to use a slightly different function, and remove the final variable:

```
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_x, $watermark_y);
```

Comment: it is work fine but when i rotate watermark it still show black background